# Combine different values of multiple columns into one column

Tags: dataframe, rust, python-polars, rust-polars

Need help to "translate" a python example to rust. The python example was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890056/combine-different-values-of-multiple-columns-into-one-column-in-polars)

Here is the code snippet I try to make work:

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let s1 = Series::new("Fruit", &["Apple", "Apple", "Pear"]);
    let s2 = Series::new("Color", &["Red", "Yellow", "Green"]);

    let df = DataFrame::new(vec![s1, s2]).unwrap();

    let df_lazy = df.lazy();

    /*

    This is the PYTHON version I like to recreate in RUST:

    df_lazy.with_columns([
                    # string fmt over multiple expressions
                    pl.format("{} has {} color", "Fruit", "Color").alias("fruit_list"),
                    # columnar lambda over multiple expressions
                    pl.map(["Fruit", "Color"], lambda s: s[0] + " has " + s[1] + " color" ).alias("fruit_list2"),
                    ])
     */

}
```

I can't even get a simple select to work?! Now I am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments ([@ polars issues](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4375)) from **@cannero** and **@ritchie46**, I was able to make it work.

This is a working version (Float64):

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn my_black_box_function(a: f64, b: f64) -> f64 {
    // do something
    a
}

fn apply_multiples(lf: LazyFrame) -> Result<DataFrame> {
   
    let ergebnis = lf
        .select([col("struct_col").map(
            |s| {
                let ca = s.struct_()?;

                let b = ca.field_by_name("a")?;
                let a = ca.field_by_name("b")?;
                let a = a.f64()?;
                let b = b.f64()?;

                let out: Float64Chunked = a
                    .into_iter()
                    .zip(b.into_iter())
                    .map(|(opt_a, opt_b)| match (opt_a, opt_b) {
                        (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(my_black_box_function(a, b)),
                        _ => None,
                    })
                    .collect();

                Ok(out.into_series())
            },
            GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Float64),
        )])
        .collect();

    ergebnis
}

fn main() {
    // We start with a normal DataFrame
    let df = df![
        "a" => [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
        "b" => [3.0, 5.1, 0.3]
    ]
    .unwrap();

    // We CONVERT the df into a StructChunked and WRAP this into a new LazyFrame
    let lf = df![
        "struct_col" => df.into_struct("StructChunked")
    ]
    .unwrap()
    .lazy();

    let processed = apply_multiples(lf);

    match processed {
        Ok(..) => println!("We did it"),
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    }
}
```

Here is a version for my initial question (String):

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn my_fruit_box(fruit: String, color: String) -> String {
    // do something
    format!("{} has {} color", fruit, color)
}

fn apply_multiples(lf: LazyFrame) -> Result<DataFrame> {
    
    let ergebnis = lf
        .select([col("struct_col").map(
            |s| {
                let ca = s.struct_()?;

                let fruit = ca.field_by_name("Fruit")?;
                let color = ca.field_by_name("Color")?;
                let color = color.utf8()?;
                let fruit = fruit.utf8()?;

                let out: Utf8Chunked = fruit
                    .into_iter()
                    .zip(color.into_iter())
                    .map(|(opt_fruit, opt_color)| match (opt_fruit, opt_color) {
                        (Some(fruit), Some(color)) => {
                            Some(my_fruit_box(fruit.to_string(), color.to_string()))
                        }
                        _ => None,
                    })
                    .collect();

                Ok(out.into_series())
            },
            GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Utf8),
        )])
        .collect();

    ergebnis
}

fn main() {
    // We start with a normal DataFrame
    let s1 = Series::new("Fruit", &["Apple", "Apple", "Pear"]);
    let s2 = Series::new("Color", &["Red", "Yellow", "Green"]);

    let df = DataFrame::new(vec![s1, s2]).unwrap();

    // We CONVERT the df into a StructChunked and WRAP this into a new LazyFrame
    let lf = df![
        "struct_col" => df.into_struct("StructChunked")
    ]
    .unwrap()
    .lazy();

    let processed = apply_multiples(lf);

    match processed {
        Ok(..) => println!("We did it"),
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The LazyFrame has a slightly different interface for `.select` than the regular DataFrame. It is expecting an iterable set of column expressions, built using the `col()` method. You can change your select call to the following:

```
let selected = df_lazy.select(&[col("Fruit"), col("Color")]);

println!("{:?}", selected.collect());
```

To get the results:

```
Ok(shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬────────┐
│ Fruit ┆ Color  │
│ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ str    │
╞═══════╪════════╡
│ Apple ┆ Red    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Apple ┆ Yellow │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Pear  ┆ Green  │
└───────┴────────┘)
```

You can see more examples of working with the LazyFrame here: https://docs.rs/polars-lazy/latest/polars_lazy/

Comment: Thanks @emagers for the help. That just leaves me with my bigger issue ... I will remove the error: `// This does not work.
    // let selected = df_lazy.select(["Fruit", "Color"]);` from the original question as this is fixed with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I got a little further ... but ran into another snag:

The [Black Box Function](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/docs/lazy/index.html#black-box-function) example should do the trick, but I can't get it to work:

> Err(SchemaMisMatch("Series of dtype: List(Float64) != Struct"))

at this line `let ca = s.struct_()?;`

Here is the sample code:

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn my_black_box_function(a: f32, b: f32) -> f32 {
    // do something
    a
}

fn apply_multiples(lf: &LazyFrame) -> Result<DataFrame> {
    df![
        "col_a" => [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
        "col_b" => [3.0, 5.1, 0.3]
    ]?
    .lazy()
    .select([concat_lst(["col_a", "col_b"]).map(
        |s| {

            let ca = s.struct_()?;

            let b = ca.field_by_name("col_a")?;
            let a = ca.field_by_name("col_b")?;
            let a = a.f32()?;
            let b = b.f32()?;

            let out: Float32Chunked = a
                .into_iter()
                .zip(b.into_iter())
                .map(|(opt_a, opt_b)| match (opt_a, opt_b) {
                    (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(my_black_box_function(a, b)),
                    _ => None,
                })
                .collect();

            Ok(out.into_series())
        },
        GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Float32),
    )])
    .collect()
}
```

The two series are concatenated as 's':

```
shape: (3,)
Series: 'col_a' [list]
[
        [1.0, 3.0]
        [2.0, 5.1]
        [3.0, 0.3]
]
```

but I can not make a `struct_` out of it?!

Answer (score 0):

To use struct_() or as_struct (see https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/custom_functions.html?highlight=apply#combining-multiple-column-values):

Add to Cargo.toml the features: "dtype-struct"

```ini
polars = { version = "*", features = [
    "lazy",
    "lazy_regex",
    "dtype-datetime",
    "strings",
    "csv-file",
    "parquet",
    "list_eval",
    "list_take",
    "concat_str",
    "dtype-struct", // <--
] }
```

Other features were added to my specific case.